# Find matched column records in one table that may be in multiple columns in a second table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables, Table 1 with multiple columns, name, ID number, address, etc.  And Table 2 with  columns, ID number 1 and ID number 2 and a few other columns.

I am trying to get a T-SQL query returning all rows in Table 1 with an indicator showing whether the ID number in Table 1 matches either  ID_1 or ID_2 in Table 2.  The result set would be all columns from Table 1 , plus  the indicator “Matched” if the ID number in Table 1 matches either ID_1 or ID_2 in Table 2.

- Table 1: ID  | Name | Address |
- Table 2: ID_1 | ID_2

Result

```
T1.ID, Name, Address, ("Matched"/"Unmatched") ...
```

Also, would it be the same to do the opposite, meaning instead of the result including all rows from Table 1 that have a matching ID in ID_1 or ID_2 in Table 2, the result set would include only records from Table 1 where t1.ID = (T2.ID_1 or T2.ID_2)?

```
 SELECT DISTINCT  
     CASE 
        WHEN (table1.ID = table2.ID_1 ) 
           THEN 'Matched'  
           ELSE 'Unmatched'  
     END AS Status ,
     table1.*
 FROM
     table1  
 LEFT JOIN 
     table2 ON table1.ID = table2.ID_1 

 UNION

 SELECT DISTINCT  
     CASE 
        WHEN (table1.ID = table2.ID_2)  
           THEN 'Matched'  
           ELSE 'Unmatched'  
     END AS Status,  
     table1.*
 FROM     
     table1  
 LEFT JOIN 
     table2 ON table1.ID = table2.ID_2
```

Comment: Please format your question.  No one is going to read that.

Answer (score 1):

I think that a correlated subquery with an `exists` condition would be a reasonable solution:

```
select
    t1.*,
    case when exists (select 1 from table2 t2 where t1.id in (t2.id_1, t2.id_2))
        then 'Matched'
        else 'Unmatched'
    end matched
from table1 t1
```

And the other way around:

```
select
    t2.*,
    case when exists (select 1 from table1 t1 where t1.id in (t2.id_1, t2.id_2))
        then 'Matched'
        else 'Unmatched'
    end matched
from table2 t2
```

If you want to "align" the rows based on the match for the whole dataset at once, then you might want to try a `full join`:

```
select t1.*, t2.*
from table1 t1
full join table2 t2 on t1.id in (t2.id_1, t2.id_2)
```